# SQL Server: xp_dirtree not showing File with Extension

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get all backup files from using xp_dirtree. I am getting list of file without extension. I would like to get all files with extension as well.

```
Declare @FileName varChar(255)
Declare @cmdText varChar(255)
Declare @BKFolder varchar(255)

set @FileName = null
set @cmdText = null
set @BKFolder = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\'


create table #FileList (
FileName varchar(255),
DepthFlag int,
FileFlag int
)


--get all the files and folders in the backup folder and put them in temporary table
insert into #FileList exec xp_dirtree @BKFolder,0,1
select * from #filelist

--get the latest backup file name
select top 1 @FileName = @BKFolder + FileName from #FileList order by filename desc
select @filename
```

[image]

reference link: http://www.playwithsql.com/2011/06/play-with-xpdirtree-to-get-files-and.html

Comment: Does the image contain the same code as already given? (I can't read that tiny image text.)

Comment: I can't reproduce, your code sample produces files with extension. (In sql server 2014)

Comment: @jarlh : It has same code as image. I am using sql server 2012. Is this issue of sql server 2012?

Comment: If the image adds nothing you can remove it. Most people here want formatted text anyway.

Comment: @jarlh : I have added image to show result of the query for reference

Comment: The result in the picture doesn't match the posted code. In the code you select `@BKFolder + FileName`, in the picture you select (presumably) every column from the temp table. Are you sure you are selecting a file? Looks like it in the picture, but is not evident from the select.

Comment: there are two select in query select * from #filelist and select @filename. I've just shown first result in screenshot. result of select * from #filelist query.

Comment: I see. Might seem a silly question, but are you sure your backup files actually have an extension? That is not necessarily the case. Like I said, I get file extentions with this code (also when I set my compatibility level to 2012). You could test it on another folder, perhaps.

Comment: Finally, I got the solution. its the issue of SQL server 2012 issue. it is working well in higher version